# Computational complexity for DFS

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity

I'm doing a dfs and would like to know how I would go about comparing the c-complexity of two filtering methods?

Method 1: Skip if visited. Added to the queue and then removed seems a waste.

```
while queue
current = queue.deque
if visited current then continue //skip loop if visited
...
```

Vs filtering before adding

```
while queue
current = queue.deque
foreach neighbor:
 if(not Visited && not queued) add //this seems like a lot of checking.
```

Would love to know how you reason through this choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithmic complexity of both methods is the same: O(m * n), where `m` is the total number of elements to visit and `n` is the number of neighbors (assuming it's the same for every element).

In first case the "n" part of the complexity is attributed to adding and removing elements to the queue + checking the visited status of the element. Each element would be added to the queue exactly n+1 times.

In the second case the "n" part of the complexity comes from the visited + queued check. These checks would be performed exactly `n` times per element.

This difference in algorithmic complexity is constant, and O notation omits constants.